# How to check an imap connection in laravel? I have tried imap_open but it doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here is my laravel code:

```
function checkUser(User $user) {

    $mbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}", $user->email, $user->password, OP_HALFOPEN);

    if ($mbox)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Error:

> imap_open(): Couldn't open stream
>   {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end he solved the problem by putting an "@" in front of the function.

CODE:

```
$mbox = @imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}", $user->email, $user->password, OP_HALFOPEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you enable settings in Gmail. You have to enable access to less secure app from settings.

https://devanswers.co/allow-less-secure-apps-access-gmail-account/

Also try enabling your `php_imap` extension php.ini file.

Try this line

```
 $mbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", $user->email, $user->password, OP_HALFOPEN);
```

Comment: I want to check the connection to an account with an if...I don't need to connect

Comment: How you will check it if you have not enabled it in gmail?

Comment: opening a connection, and checking if it has opened

Comment: Try enabling that option and check it again, then you can reset that option in gmail, also check php_imap extension in php.ini file.

Comment: I have imap enabled in php.ini.

Comment: Try above line in your code, just try adding `INBOX`

Comment: Could it be Laravel's problem?

Comment: Does not look like its laravel issue, once check by enable your gmail`s less secure app option.